# How to find duplicate numbers and display that number's frequency

Tags: java, binary-tree

I have 1000 numbers and I make a binary tree and sort the tree. It prints 0 to 100 and the other 899 numbers are duplicates. How can I keep track of the frequency of each number. Like for example the number 28 appears 9 times. Keeping a count somehow. I've been working with one method but Idk if it's close or not. I'll post that method at the end.

```
   public class bigTree {
 int data; 
 int frequency;
 bigTree Left, Right;


public bigTree makeTree(int x) {
     bigTree p; 
     p = new bigTree();
     p.data = x;
     p.Left = null;
     p.Right = null;

     return p;
 }


 public void setLeft(bigTree t, int x) {

     if (t.Left != null) {
        // setLeft(t.Left, x);
         System.out.println("Error");
     }
     else {


         t.Left = makeTree(x);
     }

 }


 public void setRight(bigTree t, int x) {

     if (t.Right != null) {
         //setRight(t.Right, x);
         System.out.println("Error");
     } else {


         t.Right = makeTree(x);
     } 
 }

 public void insertLocation(bigTree tree, int v) {

    // if (tree.data == v) {

         //findDuplicate(v);
 //}

     if (v < tree.data) {
         if (tree.Left != null){
             insertLocation(tree.Left, v);
         }
         else {
             setLeft(tree, v);
         }
    }
     if (v > tree.data) {
        if (tree.Right != null){
            insertLocation(tree.Right, v);
        } else {
        setRight(tree, v);
        }
     }

    } 


    public void sort(bigTree t) {

     if (t.Left != null) {
         sort(t.Left);

     } 
    System.out.println(t.data + " freq = " + frequency);

     if (t.Right != null) {
         sort(t.Right);
     }

     }

 public void dealArray( String[] x) {
    int convert;

    bigTree tree = makeTree(Integer.parseInt(x[0]));

     for (int i = 1; i < x.length; i++){
         //convert = Integer.parseInt(x[i]);

         insertLocation(tree, Integer.parseInt(x[i]));
        findDuplicate(Integer.parseInt(x[i]));

     }  sort(tree);
 }
```

----A method that I thought could work but isnt----

```
         public void findDuplicate(int number) {
 bigTree tree, h, q;


 tree = makeTree(number);
    //while (//there are #'s in the list) { //1st while()

        h = tree;
        q = tree;

        while (number != h.data && q != null) { //2nd while()
            h = q; 

            if (number < h.data ) {
                q = q.Left;

            } else { 
                q = q.Right;
            }
        } //end of 2nd while()

        if (number == h.data) {
            //h.frequency++;
            System.out.println("Duplcate: " + number + "freq = " + h.frequency++); 

        } 
        else {
            if (number < h.data) {
                setLeft(h,number);
            }
            else {
                setRight(h, number);
            }

        } 
 //} // End of 1st while() 
        sort(h);

 }
```

Comment: Can you explain what do you mean when you are saying that the method is not working?

Comment: Sounds like homework.. I'd use a Map with the number as the key, and the number of occurences as the value.

Comment: If this is homework, it needs to be tagged as such.

Comment: @ShaMan-H_Fel  It'll print out the duplicate, but I can't figure out how to make it print out the count(frequency) of that duplicate. In other words, everytime it sees a duplicate it'll just print out that duplicate number.

Comment: @ShaMan-H_Fel Yea I don't think that array worked

Answer (score 1):

**PrePost:**
If you need to use the binary tree search, it appears that your code above is creating a new tree for each element that it is looking for. Instead you should have a single tree that you search, add / update for each element that you are looking for.

**Previous Post:**
Although @Woot4Moo's answer will work, there is the overhead of creating the count and incrementing. I would suggest using Guava's ListMultimap class to handle all this for you.
[ListMultimap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v10.0.1/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ListMultimap.html)

```
ListMultimap<Integer, Integer> mymap;
for (Integer value : values){
    mymap.put(value, value);
}

Map<Integer, List<Integer>> asmap = mymap.asMap();
for (Entry<Integer, List<Integer>> entry : asmap.entrySet()){
    System.out.println(String.format("Value %d occurred %d times", entry.getKey(), entry.getValue().size());
}
```

Comment: I would be shocked if his professor would let him use a third party library

Comment: possibly, depends on the prof. I see no difference in using a ListMultimap vs. a Map but it is not my call. ;) However, I did update my post to address the Tree solution.

Comment: He won't lol. To be honest I never even used maps before so I have no idea how use it. It's a data structures course so everything that is taught to us is kind of making it from scratch instead of using built-in functions. Like I said in the method I have at the end of my post (findDuplicate) it will print the numbers that are appearing more than once but I can't figure out how to keep a count(frequency) every time that number comes up.

Comment: Did you see my `PrePost`? I believe I attempt to address your issue.

Answer (score 0):

So the first thing you need to do is select a data structure that can represent a value and the number of duplicates it has.  The first thing that comes to mind is a Map

`Map<Integer,Integer>` // Keeps track of the integer that is the key and the count which is the value

So what needs to happen as you parse out your array (or whatever structure you are reading this values from) is do a check on the Map like so:
myMap.contains(integerToCheck);

if contains returns true you need to increment the value stored in myMap for that key.  Else you need to insert a new key that uses `integerToCheck` and a new value of `1`  .

Then to print those values you would do the following:

```
for(Map.Entry<Integer,Integer> entry: myMap.entrySet())  
{  
    System.out.println(entry.getKey + " : " + entry.getValue());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this doesn't look difficult to do. The only problem is Idk if my teacher will accept this way of doing it. The method i posted at the end is the method he gave us, but I can't get it working.

Comment: Using a Map to store the frequency is not an optimal solution to this problem. First in half of the possible number distributions the Map will take more memory that an int array, second using this method you will miss all numbers with frequency of 0 and third you are adding additional check. A better solution will be to use int array and simply increment the necessary index.

Comment: An `int[]` only works well to hold the counters if the range of values is fairly small. Otherwise your array would be `new int[Integer.MAX_VALUE];`

Comment: @ShaMan-H_Fel actually the Map is for convenience, on account of I may one day work with Tman I want him to do it the right way, not the prematurely optimized way.  If a Map is causing the application to bottleneck it can be addressed later.

Comment: The questions states that numbers are between 0 and 100. This is fairly small number. I would use Map only if the range is either not finite or not enumerable. Of course for frequencies or values larger than Long.MAX_VALUE a special handling should be devised.

Answer (score 0):

I Think your heading in the right direction.

1) You need to sort your elements.  There is a number of ways to do this. 
[enter link description here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm)

2) You need to find the duplicate elements.  This can be done by comparing ith element with i+1 element.  You can store your answers in a Map.